# create gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i click Add button i need to create gridview dynamically, where the gridview has to contain Textbox,DatePicker and dropdownlist.where as the values entered in each row of the gridview have to store it in database and retrive.

Comment: Just ask some doubts when your doing some thing, do not give your whole work to some one.

Comment: Is this in any way different from the question you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905775/dynamically-create-textbox/1905781#1905781 ? Perhaps you could go to that question and add more details in response to the answers there? SO is a community filled with people eager to give help but as with any community you need to participate to get the most out of it.

Comment: Can you atleast try before asking people to do your work :S

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, an object is generally created dynamically in C# like this:

```
DataGridView g = new DataGridView();
```

The rest of the stuff you're asking - the textbox, datepicker, dropdownlist columns and reading/writing to the database - is quite involved and can't be answered here in any simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just Bind the `GridView` `onClick` of `Add` `Button`
Like this

```
       protected void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           objENT = new ENT();//using n-tier Architecture
            objENT.ProcType = "ProcedureType";
            DataSet ds = BLL.ProcessGrid(objENT);  
            GridviewDisplay.DataSource = ds;
            GridviewDisplay.DataBind();//GridviewBind
       }
```

I have used stored Procedure here,You can use any other methods as u wish